# UIWebView pushed up under statusbar on launch

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, webview

I am trying to build an application with a UIWebView for the iPhone.

This was working great, until in turned on rotation support in my app. Now the webview is pushed up under the status bar, when I launch the app. When I rotate it to landscape, and back to portrait, the webview is suddenly back to the wanted position.

I have included an image of what happens below.

What could possibly cause this? Should i change some settings for the webview or what could it be?

If you need anymore information, please let me know.

Screenshot:
[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [teet.dk](http://teet.dk/screen.png))</sub>

//Jens

Comment: You are using phone gap/ Titanium or else just added subview in Native Application

Comment: I have added subview, yes:

`self.wvTutorial = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[window addSubview:[wvTutorial view]];`

Am I doing it wrong, or should it be done some other way? :)

Comment: You are adding to window not view. Try adding the view to ViewController. Instead of window use `[ViewController.view addSubView:[wvTutorial view]]`

Comment: I believe that it could be something about the statusbar, the 20px indicates that. But I just can't see why? And why it only happens if autorotation is on...

Comment: I tried your code Sumanth, and it didn't work out. It gives me:
`error: Semantic Issue: Property 'view' not found on object of type 'WebViewController'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
[window addSubview:[wvTutorial view]];
```

Try doing:

```
[window.view addSubview:[wvTutorial view]];
```

Also make sure your XIB view doesn't have a status bar.

---

**EDIT**

What about

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: It tells me that:

`error: Semantic Issue: Property 'view' not found on object of type 'UIWindow *'`

Comment: You edit did the job! Thank you so much, both, for your help!
That was great. What would cause this to happen, only when using autorotate? Just out of curiosity :)

Comment: @Jens the Root View Controller property takes care of adjusting the correct frame for your UIViewController. It is resized accordingly to fit the screen and also takes care of resizing when changing orientations.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to window not view. Try adding the view to `ViewController`. Instead of window use

```
[RootViewController.view addSubView:[wvTutorial view]]
```

Comment: ibeitia's version helped me. Thank you for trying to help :)